# Как указать значения по умолчанию при деструктурирующем клонировании объекта?

Tags: javascript

можно ли при клонировании объекта в духе ( `clone = {…origin}` ) воспользоваться значениями по умолчанию?

Я делаю это через объявление переменных:

```
const {a = 1, b = 2, c = 3} = origin
const clone = {a, b, c }
```

Можно ли уложиться в один литерал?

Comment: добавь пример origin и результата

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значение по умолчанию можно вставить непосредственно перед `...`, либо в качестве объекта:

```js
var origin = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b'
}
var clone = {
  a: '1',
  b: '2',
  c: '3',
  ...origin
}

console.log(clone);

var clone = { ...{
    a: '1',
    b: '2',
    c: '3'
  },
  ...origin
}
console.log(clone);
```